# Number of critical points of $f(x)=(x+\ln x)^x$ on $[1,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

> How many critical points does the function $f(x)=(x+\ln x)^x$ has on $[1,\infty)$?

Here Since $x$ and $\ln x$ and $a^x$ (for $a>0$) are strictly increasing, we can conclude that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on $[1,\infty)$ and I thought it is enough to conclude $f'(x)=0$ has no solution but as a counterexample $g(x)=x^3$ is also strictly increasing but $g'(0)=0$. But I'm wondering is it possible to prove it has no critical point without calculating derivative?

By the way derivative is $f'(x)=(x+\ln x)^x\times (\ln(x+\ln x)+\frac{x+1}{x+\ln x})$ and it is not hard to recognize it has no critical points from it.

Answer (score 1):

First, let us prove that, for all $1 \le a < x$,
$$f(x) - f(a) \ge x - a. \tag{1}$$
Indeed, we have
\begin{align*}
 f(x) - f(a) &\ge (x + \ln a)^a - (a + \ln a)^a \\
 &= (a + \ln a)^a \left(1 + \frac{x - a}{a + \ln a}\right)^a
 - (a + \ln a)^a\\
 &\ge (a + \ln a)^a \left(1 + \frac{x - a}{a + \ln a}\right)
 - (a + \ln a)^a \\
 &= (a + \ln a)^{a - 1}(x - a)\\
 &\ge x - a.
\end{align*}

Second, if $f'(a) = 0$ for some $a \ge 1$, then (1) is impossible.

Thus, $f'(x) = 0$ has no real solution on $[1, \infty]$.